# Ошибка времени выполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат. Строка номер 8

Tags: pascal

```
Program tabl;
{табуляция функции}
var
X, XN, XK, DX, Z:real;
i: integer;
Begin
writeln ('Введите хнач., хкон., шаг  ');
readln (XN, XK, DX);
{Вывод заголовка таблицы}
writeln (' ':5,'функция z=EXP (-X)');
for i:=1 to 26 do
write ('_');
writeln();
writeln ('|     X      |     Z      |');
for i:=1 to 26 do 
write ('-');
writeln ();
{Рабочая часть программы}
X:=XN;
While X>=XK do
Begin
if x>=1 then
Z:=sqrt(abs(2*x+(ln(x))*ln(x))) else
if (x>-1) and (x<1) then
Z:=(sqr((pi/2)-arcsin(x)))/2 else
if (x<-1) then
Z:=exp(2*x)*ln(sqr(x)+1/ln(10));
Writeln ('|', X:10:3, '|', Z:10:3, '|');
X:=X+DX
End;
{Вывод низа таблицы}               
for i:=1 to 26 do write ('_');
writeln ();
End.
```

Найдите и исправьте ошибку, пожалуйста. Данные такие: -4 4 0,4

Comment: Там надо ввести 3 числа, они такие -4; 4; 0,4

Comment: теперь точки с запятой откуда-то взялись

Answer (score 1):

Викторина? -4 4 0.4

Если запятая - десятичный знак - обязательна, читайте строки и конвертируйте их в числа, используя `StrToFloat` (или что там есть в чистом Паскале для конвертации с учетом *Regional Settings*).